# How do I setup Python3.3 and Sublime Text 2 correctly on OS X 10.8.2?

Tags: macos, text-editor, python, sublimetext

I am trying to setup Sublime Text 2 so that the build command correctly runs Python3 / Python3.3 scripts.

I have installed Python 3.3 via the installer obtained from python.org and installed Sublime Text 2 via the Sublime Text 2 installer.

Following this I added a custom build entry called:

```
Python3.sublime-build
```

into Sublime Text 2's Python folder with the following contents:

```
{
    "cmd": ["python3", "-u", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python"
}
```

I'm getting the following error when trying to run the script:

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory
[cmd:  [u'python3', u'-u', u'/Users/user/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/Python/Python3.sublime-build']]
[dir:  /Users/user/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/Python]
[path: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin]
[Finished]
```

I have read somewhere that symlinkng `python3` from `/usr/bin` might fix the issue but after creating the symlink in `/usr/bin` through Finder, Sublime Text still cannot build as it gets a permissions error.

What is the best way to set Sublime Text 2 up to allow for running Python3 scripts?

[edit]

If I place the PATH for the python3 simlink generated by install, Sublime Text 2 can build the script,

```
    {
        "cmd": ["usr/local/bin/python3", "-u", "$file"],
        "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
        "selector": "source.python"
    }
```

But when I tried adding the PATH to the ~/.MacOSX/environment.plist as advised without the defined PATH I get the error. Could anyone point out why this is not working?

Comment: Do you mean building Python 3 - that normally means getting the sources and building the python executable? I think you mean using Python 3 ie running a .py script through a python3 executable

Comment: Yes I mean running the build command for a python script in SublimeText2 not building Python - will edit to clarify.

Comment: Thank you for editing in the code blocks, first question I have asked, will have to remember them next time.

Answer (score 4):

Add `"path": "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin/"` to your Python3 build file. Mine looks like this:

```
{
    "cmd": ["python3", "-u", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python",
    "encoding": "utf8",
    "path": "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin/"
}
```

Note: *Make sure the path to Python3 is relative to **your** machine - that was true for mine*

Comment: I'm doing the same with the line "cmd": ["usr/local/bin/python3", "-u", "$file"], really looking for a solution to have OSX do the leg work for me.

Comment: @markfknight try using `$(which python)` in the build file.

Answer (score 2):

I gave the complete path to python3 to get this to work:

```
{
  "cmd" : ["/usr/local/bin/python3", "-u", "$file"],
}
```

Comment: This was the trick for mine.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is the normal OSX one that GUI Applications do not read your shell profiles etc and so just have the path inherited from the Workspace.

The way to fix this is to add the path in ~/.MacOSX/environment.plist

That is add a key string pair for PATH e.g.

```
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>

  <key>PATH</key>
  <string>/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/libexec/binutils:</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

You will need to logout and login or possibly reboot for this to work.

Comment: Created the folder and file before adding the key string pair, unfortunately I am still getting the error. do I need to add the path of Pyhton3 to the binary as well?

Comment: What does the path output in SublimeText show now?

Comment: the path output is still showing [path: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin]

Comment: I have added <Key>PATH<Key> and the following <String>/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:<String> to ~/.MacOSX/environment.plist, shutdown and started up, still getting this message.  If I link directly to /usr/local/bin/python3 in the Python3.sublime-build file its builds with no issues. Can you help further?

Comment: Adding to the Sublime build probably is best

Answer (score 0):

Sister site stackoverflow has few entries with explanations regarding the issue of setting PATH environment variables for GUI based applications. Some claim that environment.plist works and others claim it doesn't and recommend using launched.conf.

[Mac OS X Lion no longer recognizes environment.plist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6770411/mac-os-x-lion-no-longer-recognizes-environment-plist), [Environment variables in Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/603785/environment-variables-in-mac-os-x/4567308#4567308), and [Set environment variables on Mac OS X Lion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7501678/set-environment-variables-on-mac-os-x-lion). Also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/588442/945915) has more details about launched.conf format.

Comment: Have tried both of these during my searches with no luck.